# node.js mongoose is not reponding on save

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm making a register user but when its saving, mongoose is not responding, i mean, it does nothing i ask it to do, it just do nothing, its really saving but its not making the render i'm asking it to do, here's my code:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    username: String,
    password: String
});

//User model.
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

app.post('/register', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('REGISTER OK');

    //set connection to mongodb.
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

    var db = mongoose.connection;


    //Connect to mongodb.
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback()
    {

        console.log('connection succeed.');


        UserModel.findOne({username: request.body.username}, function(error, data)
        {
            if(error)
                console.log(error);

            if(data)
            {
                response.render('register',
                {
                    'Title': Title,
                    'result': 'user found'
                });

                mongoose.connection.close();
            }

            else
            {
                var user = new UserModel(
                {
                    username: request.body.username,
                    password: request.body.password
                });


                user.save(function(error, data)
                {
                    if(error)
                        console.log(error);

                   console.log('saved');
                });

                mongoose.connection.close();
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

for now i've removed the render code and just make it log 'saved' but its not logging, for now its just making the save into mongodb.

Comment: Well my bet is that you're closing the connection before the server can respond to that save you're making and so the callback for `.save` never gets called. To check if that's the case, put the `connection.close` invocation inside your save callback.

Comment: @guessimtoolate well, i did what you metioned, but it gave me a mongo error telling me that connection was being closed, i put it back again, but this time i was making the render, and it worked, not clue how...